# Graph creation problems in Tensorboard from Google Developers videos

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

So I was watching the Google Developers video on youtube 
[Hands-on TensorBoard (TensorFlow Dev Summit 2017)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4&t=243s)
and I have a lot of problem recreating his graph at time [6:01](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4&t=361s).

The following is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

#1. add some name for w and b
#2. apply name scope

def conv_layer(input, channels_in, channels_out, name = "conv"):
    with tf.name_scope(name): 
        w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5, 5, channels_in, channels_out]), name = "W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([channels_out]), name = "B")
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")
        act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
        return act

#1. add some name for w and b
#2. apply name scope

def fc_layer(input, channels_in, channels_out, name = "fc"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([channels_in, channels_out]), name = "W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([channels_out]), name = "B")
        act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input,w) + b)
        return act

#1. add some name for placeholders, cov layer, fc, logits
#2. apply name scope

# Setup placeholders, and reshape the data
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name = "x")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name = "labels")
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 32, "conv1")
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = "SAME")

conv2 = conv_layer(pool1, 32, 64, "conv2")
pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = "SAME")
flattened = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])

fcl = fc_layer(flattened, 7*7*64, 1024, "fcl")
logits = fc_layer(fcl, 1024, 10, "fc2")

added name scope and changed the name for cross_entropyu

with tf.name_scope("xent"):
    xent = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels = y))


#cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
#    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels = y))

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(xent)

with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/Users/jianxiongji/graphs/change3/")
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```

And my graph looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvzNk.png), but what he had in his presentation is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG4cK.jpg).

I am quite confused; maybe I missed something or just plainly wrong, but there was no error shown in the code above when I run it.

I wanna thank you all ahead of time for helping me. I would appreciate a lot if you can provide me some good tutorial or material on tensorboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code snippet and tensorboard showed the graph exactly like on the video. So the code is correct. Your picture is most probably presenting another graph. A number of reasons for this:

- There are `xent` and `accuracy` name scopes, plus `xent_1` and `accuracy_1`. This duplication means that you had defined `xent` and `accuracy` twice (e.g., this is easily possible in jupyther).
- There are `Variable`, `Variable_1`, ..., `Variable_7`, but all of your variables have names.

So tensorboard is likely looking at your early attempts to recreate the graph. Try cleaning up your log directories and do a clean run. Then make sure that tensorboard is invoked with `--logdir /Users/jianxiongji/graphs/change3/`. If you're using jupyther restart the backend and rebuild all cells.